# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing' or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, system.drawing, invalidoperationexception

I'm getting this error since yesterday and after 'searching trying and crying' I've ended up asking the question on here.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in '*project*.exe'
>
> The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This project is set to use the 3.5-Framework. The error occurs when the form loads, when my resources have images or anything that uses graphics in it.
(removing the form-icon and button-images *'solves'* the problem).
I've allready tried the following :

1. Performed a 'Clean' & 'Rebuild' on the project
2. Removed the System.Drawing reference, and added it back in.
3. Set accessmodifier for the resource in the *.resx to 'no code generation'.
4. Searching the *resx-file for '4.0.0.0' to replace with '2.0.0.0' but '4.0.0.0' was not listed anywhere.

This question has been raised in the past, yet no suggestions seem to fix my problem ?

Thanks for reading. Thanks for your time.
Bert

Comment: Sure, you have a resource that still refers to 4.0.  Usual mishap is starting the project targeting 4.0+ and then changing it to 3.5.  It is not necessarily easy to find, some resources are encoded in base64 in the .resx file.  Like a bitmap or icon.  The stack trace of the exception ought to give you a pretty good idea which specific resource is the troublemaker.  You'll have to reload the form in the designer and make a trivial edit to get it to re-generate the .resx file.

Comment: Could it be that you are referencing an assembly version 4.0 from a .net 3.5 project ?

Comment: I don't remember ever having this project(s) on 4.0 . Nor switching it back to 3.5 afterwards. It worked all dandy and fine yesterday. i'll try to 'edit' the form.ico to regen the .resx file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried to remember what changed before this error started to occur, i remember setting a System variable I set :

[image: System var]

Trying to fix the buggy error

*MSBUILD : error MSB4017: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR2" and architecture "x86".*

1. Closed Visual studio
2. Removed said System Variable
3. Rebuild solution (without even editing any icons/images)

Now it works ... Strange !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try the following

1. Check in ildasm of there are any DLL that still references to the v4.0 of System.Drawing DLL
2. Add a binding redirect in your web.config so that the version redirection happens properly.

HTH

Comment: No sign of an 4.0 system.drawing dll. As this is a win-form project, it's normal that i don't have a web.config, right ?